# Missing $ inserted (multicolumn)

Tags: math-mode

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Part}
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\sigma_{I}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\sigma_{II}} \\ \cline{2-5}
```

I am compiling this code, I am getting the error `Missing $ inserted` and after that it is giving me the desired result. But still I dont wan't any errors in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably (you could have said) you are in a `tabular` rather than an `array` so it defaults to text mode so to get a sigma you need

```
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\sigma_{I}$}
```